# Where can I find the loadavg.c file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, load-average

Ubuntu version: Linux version 5.15.0-52-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-032) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38)

Other places say it can be found as fs/proc/loadavg.c but I don't have it.
Where can I find the loadavg.c file?

Comment: It's part of the kernel source. Install a kernel source package. Or google `loadavg.c`. I would be surprised if this is one of the files Ubuntu patches.

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/loadavg.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file is part of Linux kernel source, which is not installed in Ubuntu by default. You need to [pull it manually](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel#Obtaining_the_source_for_an_Ubuntu_release):

```
apt-get source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
```

(for this to work you need to have `deb-src` lines enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, they are OK by default).

Or you can explore the latest "vanilla" source online at [Linux kernel GitHub mirror](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/loadavg.c).